# the general solution of the motion in the xy-plane of cyclotron for given E and B

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

A particle of charge e and mass m moves in a region of uniform electric field E directed along Ox and a uniform magnetic field B directed along Oz.
Show that one solution (called a particular integral) is x=0, y=-Et/B,z=0,
and that the general solution of the motion in the xy-plane is
x= R sinw(t-t0)+x0
y= R cosw(t-t0)+y0-Et/B
where w=eB/m is the cyclotron frequency. Thus the particle executes circles superposed upon a drift velocity E/B perpendicular to both **E** and **B**. The radius R and other constants are determined by the initial conditions.

By using the Lorentz force,
i get
[image]

Comment: I would suggest starting from the Lorentz force, constructing some general position and velocity vectors to work with in this Lorentz force expression

Comment: Consider taking the time derivative of the second order differential equation in y and equating the x derivative terms.